# What's the easiest way to install Enlightenment on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager, enlightenment

I've found a few guides but all of them are really complicated. Is there an `apt-get` way of installing the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[This](https://launchpad.net/~e17-packaging/+archive/ppa)** is the PPA of the team packaging it for ubuntu .

Once you add the PPA to the repositories, you can then use synaptics to install it. As of today, the repo is updated with packages for Jaunty. I did not try it myself, but it could work for karmic esily.

**EDIT:** ~quack in the comments suggests to rebuild packages for Karmic from PPA sources... that seems like a sound idea to me!

Comment: i don't recommend installing Jaunty packages on Karmic.  you might get away with rebuilding those .debs (from the PPA's sources) on Karmic, and then installing those.

Comment: It seems like a sound idea (+1). Added in the main text of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want e17 as it is the newest and most feature-packed version. There is a good walk-through here:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-e17-enlightenment-desktop-in-ubuntu.html

It is not for Karmic, but all the steps work. I'm running 10.04 pre-alpha and this worked on my system just fine. If you don't like that version, use the easy_e17 script, explained here:

http://wiki.enlightenment.org/index.php/E17_on_Ubuntu

Comment: The how-to you linked contains repositories for Ubuntu Edgy (AD 2006!)... I suspect the version of e17 in there could hardly be defined "then newest"! ;)

Comment: Fair enough, it has obviously been modified since then, but if you wanted to be on the edge of it, running the daily build (2nd link) would be preferable anyway.